# Remove uneven line ending positions in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, newlines

In the attached picture, you can see that each line of text ends abruptly in between without going to the end of the actual position where a line should end(the rightmost location).

[image]

With formatting options turned on I have something like this

[image: with formatting options turned on]

I have about a file with 250 pages like this, so fixing the lines manually is out of the question. Is there a way to make the lines even by selecting one para at a time maybe, since there are locations where actually a paragraph ends and another begins, and I don't want them to join !!

Comment: Please post a new image with all formatting markers turned on.

Comment: @DavidPostill, what formatting markers??

Comment: "There are many formatting marks in Word document, such as tab characters, spaces, paragraph marks, hidden text, optional hyphens, object anchors, optional breaks and so on. " - [How to show or hide formatting marks in Word?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/904-word-show-hide-formatting-marks.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill, Did, i hope that its useful

Comment: [How to Remove Extra Paragraph Marks in a Word Document](https://gadgetwise.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/05/31/q-a-how-to-remove-extra-paragraph-marks-in-a-word-document/) should get you started. 1/ replace `.` followed by a paragraph mark with `.ZZ` and no paragraph mark. 2/ replace all paragraph marks with nothing. 3/ replace all `.ZZ` with `.` and a paragraph mark. If ZZ appears in your doc use some other unique sequence.

Comment: Word is not being able to find any such character, for a paragraph the special character that is being shown is ^v, i wonder if this is correct!!!

Comment: No, something is wrong, it should be ^p. See [Replacing special characters](http://www.officetooltips.com/word_2016/tips/replacing_special_characters.html). ^v isn't even in the list.